# graph-tool: Efficient way to check if vertex exists before adding it

Tags: python-3.x, graph-tool

I understand that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787443/python-graph-tool-access-vertex-properties) and the docs that *find_vertex* runs at O(N). I'm using the function to check if a vertex with a String property I'm adding already exists. Is this the optimal method to check if a graph already contains a vertex with a string property?

I'm trying to figure if I can use Property Maps like a dictionary to see if a string exists already before adding a vertex. Is it possible to access a Property Map by its value rather than its key since my Property Map values are unique anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42808665) of your linked question, a faster option is to create a python dict to store string and vertex pairs. Then you only need `O(1)` for the check.